# Why so many backslashes in this preg_match for resolving namespaces?

Tags: php, preg-match

A book I'm reading has this code but cant understand why so many backslashes in `preg_match`. The first \ might mean to match literal backslash but why two more in the expression?

This is code to "provide namespace support" with autoload:

```
// listing 05.18
$namespaces = function ($path) {
    if (preg_match('/\\\\/', $path)) {
        $path = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    }
    if (file_exists("{$path}.php")) {
        require_once("{$path}.php");
    }
};
\spl_autoload_register($namespaces);
$obj = new util\LocalPath();
$obj->wave();
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP (like many languages) requires backslashes to be escaped with backslashes. Regular expressions also require backslashes to be escaped with backslashes. Thus, to match a single literal backslash, in a regular expression string, you must use `\\\\`: PHP converts the string into two escaped backslashes, which the regular expression parser sees as one escaped backslash.

Answer (score 0):

1. I want to match: `\`
2. So I need the regex: `/\\/`
3. It needs to be represented in PHP by a string, so that looks like: `'/\\\\/'`.